# intermittent page laod failure in IOS Safari browser

Tags: ios, aem, mobile-safari

I have a mobile-app, which loads page in an iFrame.

I am receiving intermittent page-load failures(scripts, css and image resources are throwing 303 response code). The page is built using AEM.

This is happening once out of 10 times of page-load. Also, it doesn't happen on Android device.

Exact error in network tab:
Failed to load resource: The operation couldn't be completed. (**kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303**).

I had gone through portals about KCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error(On AppleForums and macReports.com). But, don't think that this is an application related issue.

Any pointers or ideas might help!

Comment: Any logs on the AEM side?

Comment: No, there wasn't any specific errors captured on AEM. It's just, we see 303 failures in console. I can see most of the resource calls have failed in network tab.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Not yet. I haven't reached on the root-cause!